# Add new image size to media uploader so users can insert into post?

Tags: images

I would like to create an additional size for uploaded images which my users can then "insert into post". I understand that add_image_size() will add a new image size which I can use in my theme, but that new size isn't available on the media upload screen.

Is there a way to get new sizes to appear on that screen so they're available to people as they add/edit posts? I have a tweaky theme that needs more than just the default 3 sizes + original.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just found a new plugin which seems to do exactly what I described above:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/additional-image-sizes-zui/

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

Even though we create our image size we will need additional code to add it into the Media Uploaders dropdown of available sizes. First let's register the size. We can use the [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) or [`after_setup_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/) hook:

```
function theme_init() {
    add_image_size( 'banner_image', 1200, 200, true );
}
add_action( 'init', 'theme_init' );
```

We need to use the [`image_size_names_choose`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_size_names_choose/) hook to add in the new size into the available sizes. The [Developer Resources suggests](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/#for-media-library-images-admin) using the following:

```
/**
 * @param Array $default_sizes - Array( 'size_slug' => 'Size Title' )
 *
 * @return Array $default_sizes
 */
function image_sizes_to_mediapicker( $default_sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $default_sizes, array(
        'banner_image' => __( 'Banner Image' ),
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'image_sizes_to_mediapicker' );
```

The above works fine but maybe we can automate this a bit. The below assumes that any additional sizes are named with underscores so it may not be an optimal solution that works with plugins that add their own sizes. It is also heavily commented to show what each variable is.

```
/**
 * @param Array $default_sizes - Array( 'size_slug' => 'Title' )
 *
 * @return Array $return_sizes
 */
function image_sizes_to_mediapicker( $default_sizes ) {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;                             // All additionally added sizes

    $size_slugs     = array_keys( $_wp_additional_image_sizes );    // Get array of additional sizes
    $default_slugs  = array_keys( $default_sizes );                 // Get array of default sizes
    $exclude_sizes  = array( 'medium_large' );                      // Exclude any image sizes
    // $exclude_sizes = get_option( 'mediapicker_exlcuded_sizes', array() )             // IF we want to previously set / retrieve an array of excluded options
    $sizes_needed   = array_diff( $size_slugs, $default_slugs, $exclude_sizes );        // Get difference between the defaults and additional sizes
    $return_sizes   = $default_sizes;                               // Let's keep separation between passed and returned

    foreach( $sizes_needed as $size_slug ) {
        $pretty_title               = ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', $size_slug ) );   // Create a pretty title
        $return_sizes[ $size_slug ] = __( $pretty_title );
    }

    return $return_sizes;
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'image_sizes_to_mediapicker' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I cracked open the code and there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

The list of thumbnail sizes that WP iterates through while rendering those radio buttons is hard-coded, and there don't seem to be any filters or actions to hook in to.

This is really strange. I'd fully expect there to be a way to do this.

Do people need to be able to insert ANY of your custom sizes into posts at any given time? Or are some of them only used in templates? I guess what I'm asking is, is it possible to just make one or more of the default sizes (thumb, medium, large) the ones that get added in posts, and save any additional versions for custom sizes? Know what I mean?

Comment: Thanks for looking! I don't need all my custom sizes available, but I do need the defaults + one more. I did find a pair of plugins that together will enable me to do this: Max Image Size Control (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/max-image-size-control/) + WP Smart Image II (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-smart-image-ii/). But, I don't really want to add 2 plugins for something that seems like it should be so simple. Guess I need to backward-engineer what those plugins are doing... Thanks again!!